# Partitions when dual booting 2 copies of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, dualboot

I have a single 1TB NVMe in my Dell PC and I'd like to install a second copy of Windows 10. I know the basic process of Dual Booting but I have a question about the partitions that already existed on the Dell.

The Dell came with a 512GB NVMe which I have replaced and cloned to the 1TB NVMe. This is successfully booting (as I am using it now) and has left me with 455GB of unallocated space at the end:

[image: 1TB NVMe Partition Layout]

My query is are the partitions in the correct places for the second copy of Windows 10 to be installed? Will the installer just figure things out?

**Note: I do have enough licenses to install 2 copies of Windows 10 :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to worry about regarding partition position. Your system likely uses UEFI instead of BIOS which knows about partitions and there are plenty of space for the file system driver in the ESP so the boot loader can boot any NTFS partitions

Even on older BIOS systems you also don't need care about those things. Windows Vista and up uses NT60 boot loader which can boot even logical partitions, unlike NT52 boot loader on XP which can only boot from primary partitions. And all the NT boot loaders don't actually care about the position of the boot partition. Only ancient BIOSes that can't boot from drives larger than 2GB have such limitations

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it would be a problem, but I stupidly wiped the original NVMe before really thinking otherwise I could have just tried it and re-cloned if it failed. I'll go ahead tonight. Worst case.... I have to rebuild from scratch! Thanks

Comment: Went ahead and installed the second copy. Had a small issue first time and had to wipe the new partitions but second time all went well and I am dual booting. Many thanks!